# How to interact with Bootstrap Popover using Capybara Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, testing, capybara, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm trying to test that pressing a button inserts a new record into the DB (Rails 5b3)

The button is in a bootstrap popover and function it runs works well.  However, when I try to test it, I can't seem to target the element.

The content of the popover is not on the DOM by default, it's inserted and removed upon click of a button.  This is the default behavior in Bootstrap v4

Here's my testing gem set:

```
  gem "rails-controller-testing", :git => "https://github.com/rails/rails-controller-testing"
  gem 'launchy'
  gem 'poltergeist'
  gem 'rspec', '~> 3.5.0.beta1'
  gem 'rspec-core', '~> 3.5.0.beta1'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.5.0.beta1'
  gem 'guard-rspec', '~> 4.6', require: false
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
```

Here's the relevant HTML inserted by the popover I'm trying to target:

```
<button data-js-method="createblock" class='btn btn-secondary btn-block'>Heading</button>
```

And here is my test:

```
scenario 'Popover#Heading' do
  before_count = HeadingBlock.count
  # This clicks the button to activate the popover
  find('.btn-add-block').click

  # The line below is what I'm trying to target
  # click_button('Heading') yields 'Unable to find button "Heading"'
  find('button [data-js-method="createblock"]').click
  after_count = HeadingBlock.count

  expect(after_count - before_count).to eq(1)
end
```

Finally, the error:

```
Capybara::ElementNotFound:
       Unable to find css "button [data-js-method=\"createblock\"]"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In CSS selectors a space means to find a descendant, but you're looking to match the attribute of the button element. Therefore it should be

```
find('button[data-js-method="createblock"]').click #no space between button and [data-....
```

I'm not sure why click_button('Heading') isn't working for you since you don't indicate what error you get when trying that.

Next is the issue that clicking the button may take some time to process, so getting the count immediately may be flaky.  You should be using the `expect(page).to have_selector('whatever selector', count: before_count+1)`   so that capybaras waiting/retry behavior can work for you -- I don't know what that selector should be because I don't know what `HeadingBlock` is defined as.

Comment: Using your CSS selector yields the same result.  Using click_button('Heading') results in 'Unable to find button "Heading"'.  I don't understand the second half of your post.  HeadingBlock is a model, and I'm checking to see if pressing the button has created a new entry in the database.  

Would you mind elaborating?

Comment: If the selector is also giving "Unable to find" then your button is not visible on the page.  Are you sure you don't have to do some other action to make the button visible, or is it taking longer than whatever you have Capybara.default_max_wait_time set to? You can test that by doing `click_button('Heading', wait: 20)` to make sure it's working.  Your next issue is that `#click` is asynchronous so checking the database immediately after calling doesn't give the app time to create the new record.  You are much better off when testing checking for changes that appear on the screen instead ...

Comment: of counting items in the database.  So once you create the new Heading if it appears on the page, check for that with have_selector rather than counting the database items - that way Capybara can wait for changes to appear - otherwise you need a sleep between the click and the database count call so the action can finish.  If you insist on doing database counts you can look at the `become_eq` matcher from https://github.com/abotalov/waiting_rspec_matchers which will retry the database count for a time until it matches - something like  `expect {HeadingBlock.count}.to become_eq(before_count+1)`

Comment: Here is what I'm trying to do.  The first click in my test emulates clicking the "+" button, and the one I'm having trouble with is clicking the 'heading' button.  https://gfycat.com/FreshIdenticalBlackandtancoonhound

Thank you very much for the other info!  I'll look into implementing that when I get this sorted.

Comment: From the video, assuming "Heading" is actually a button element (rather than an a element stlyed to look like a button)- it looks like `click_button('Heading')` should work. Since you have poltergeist listed as a gem do you have Capybara.default_driver set to :poltergeist (you don't have `js: true` on your scenario so I assume you're running all tests as JS enabled??)

Comment: I have `Capybara.javascript_driver = :poltergeist` (not default_driver) in my `RSpec.configure do |config|` block.  I did not have js: true on the scenario, however when I add it, it causes `click_link 'New Story'` (which is run before using `background do ... `) to fail with the error `Unable to find link "New Story"`

Comment: ok -- so you have a JS dependent scenario (without JS the popover can't work) so you need `js: true` on the scenario.  Why your other `click_link` wouldn't work I have no no clue without more info.  Since you're using poltergeist make sure you have the latest phantomjs (2.1.1) installed - and if that doesn't fix it - enable the poltergeist debug mode - https://github.com/teampoltergeist/poltergeist#customization - and see if that gives you any clue

Comment: Here's the entire scenario - it's very bare bones http://puu.sh/oboJR/75493bd775.png.  Phantom is fully updated.  I'll try debug mode.  Thank you!

Comment: Theres no `visit` in that scenario - you need to visit a url in order to have a link to click

Comment: My apologies, I do have a visit in a `background` block above.  The link I'm trying to click definitely exists on the page

Comment: If capybara is telling you it can't find the link, then the link either isn't visible on the page, or it's not actually loading the page you think it is.  You can put a `sleep 5; puts page.html`  as first thing in your scenario (after the visit) and see what the html for the page is.  You could also try running with selenium instead of poltergeist  (add a `driver: :selenium` tag to the scenario instead of :js) and see what page it's loading in the actual browser

Comment: This issue resolved when I included database_cleaner.  Thanks for the help!